# Using acceleration to plot position

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, kinematics

Sorry if this question is dumb, and I know is physics 101, but I'm not that good with physics.

I'm writing an iPhone program that by collecting the acceleration data of the device tries to replicate the motion of the device in an virtual environment.

To simplify things, let's consider just one axis.

If the device is at position 0 with acceleration 0 and speed 0, if it receives an acceleration of 1.25G, what it will be it's position after 1.22 seconds, considering that the acceleration will last for the whole 1.22 seconds?

Comment: If you know how to calculate the final speed, divide the final speed by two to get the average speed, and multiply the average speed by the time to get the distance.

Comment: the laws of motion should help, s=ut+1/2 at^2 etc.  Any a-level text book will have all the details.

Comment: Hi Nicolae, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! You're right that this is kind of a trivial question at face value - not because it's "physics 101" level, but because all you need to do is look up a formula. It's as if you go to the [english.SE] site and ask them for a synonym of, say, "complicated" - they'll just tell you that you should have checked a thesaurus. SE sites are not really the place for such "general reference" questions. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) But you're lucky in that there is a sense in which I think this question could be more complex: you will have to not only know the equation, but also numerically _compute_ the position by integrating the acceleration over time, and there are some subtleties involved in that sort of numerical computation which a good answer could definitely address.

Comment: The only way this gets interesting if if you don't know how the phone is oriented, it if the orientation is changing. There are some neat ways I can imagine to estimate that missing data, but your accuracy will still degrade over time.

Comment: @ColinK The accelerometer also gives me the gravity acceleration (I don't know exactly the english term, hope I got it right) so I know how the phone is oriented.

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu: Actually no, you don't. How do you separate the gravitational acceleration from the other components? Given some acceleration measurement, you know that some part of it is due to gravity, but without knowing the orientation of the phone relative to gravity, you don't know how to subtract gravity to get the acceleration you're looking for. Even worse, knowing the direction of gravity will not tell you how the phone is rotated in a plane parallel to the ground.

Comment: To filter out the gravity out of the allceleration, it's already done (I use a low-pass filter on the acceleration data, if I'm not wrong). But your second point might be valid: you can't detect if the phone rotates in a plane parallel to the ground. Although, the phone would have to rotate around the accelerometer sensor in order to not pick up the rotation, which I don't believe it's in the center of the device. I need to check this, but most probably you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are looking for the position, say $s$, of the object at a certain time $t$. Given initial conditions $t_0$ (initial time), $v_0$ (velocity at $t_0$), $s_0$ (position at $t_0$) and a constant acceleration $a$ during a time interval $t - t_0$.

We use the following equation to determine the position $s$ at time $t$:

$$s = s_0 + v_0(t-t0) + \frac {1}{2}a(t-t_0)^2$$

([This page](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/301/lectures/node12.html) would be helpful if you need more.)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are fine if the accelerations are constant enough. If you collect the data with the accelerometer of the device, there's a very good chance that the accelerations you're dealing with is not constant.

There are some numerical integration methods (Euler, Verlet, Runge-Kutta, ...) to integrate the accelerations of moving bodies, so we can know its position as a function of time. You can do a bit of research on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_ordinary_differential_equations), pick one that you understand (I don't recommend Euler however). Still, the methods (especially the second-order ones) are often based on the fact that the equation $ s = s_0 + v_0 t + \frac12 gt^2 $ holds approximately true for small intervals of time.