# How to find acceleration given position and velocity?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, vectors, simulations, integration

Sorry for this very simple question but I am still very new to the laws of [motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematics).

I am dealing with 2-dimensional vectors in my programming environment and I'm following [these slides](http://www.richardlord.net/presentations/physics-for-flash-games) to learn about simple integrators.

Near the end of the slides for the 4th Order Runge Kutta Integrator he is calculating acceleration like this:

```
a2 = acceleration(p2, v2)
```

However, I'm not quite sure where that function is defined in the slides. I'm sure the answer is very simple but for all prior slides the acceleration was always constant.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18173/2451

Comment: You may be interested in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is seems to more about software than physics. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function is not defined there because you want to use a different one, depending on what kind of motion you're modelling. Using the obvious Newton law
$$
  a \propto F,
$$
you can think of it as calculating the *force* that acts on your object, e.g. the spring force. In the case of gravitation, you simply put in the constant gravity acceleration downwards.

(I'd like to note that in this case, 4th order Runge-Kutta is something of an overkill as 2nd order is already *exact*! But it's nevertheless a good idea to use it here, to be consistent: 4th-order Runge-Kutta is used in a very wide range of applications.)

Comment: Sorry but that's what symbol between the a and F mean?

Comment: Proportionality. You can also write $F=m\cdot a$, with $m$ constant.

Comment: Alright thanks! Yeah I wrote a console application comparing euler, improved euler, and runge kutta but I can't find a scenario where runge kutta and improved euler don't give the same results.. You said 4th-order runge-kutta is used in a lot of applications.. I hope it's not too off-topic to ask when and why it's needed?

Comment: @JohnTylerc: as soon as you have multiple particles interacting in some way, RK4 performs much better. In nontrivial classical physics simulations, there are of course always more than two particles involved (otherwise you'd just calculate the time-evolution analytically, for all times in one go1) – it's certainly different in e.g. game development.